# Pixelated smoke in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation

Every time I render mmy smoke sim out, it looks pixelated. What setting do I need to change?[image]

Comment: The resolution of your smoke domain is probably too low.

Comment: Resolution is 200 with a High Resolution division of 2